How to "eval" a multi-line command?
Hello and thanks for the help.
I ssh into several computers and execute a <Block-of-commands> on each.
I've added a new computer that does not allow ssh.
So <Block-of-commands> must be executed locally on this computer, not through ssh.
ORIGINAL CODE:
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "Computer" ]; then
 "bash -c '
  <Block-of-commands>    #Block-of-commands done locally on "Computer"
 '"
else
 ssh "Name@RemoteComputer" "bash -c '
  <Block-of-commands>    #Block-of-commands done remotely using ssh
 '"
fi

Unfortunately, the above code requires duplication the <Block-of-commands>, which complicates changes to <Block-of-commands>.
(I could make <Block-of-commands> a separate file and call it, but that's just another complication.  I'd like to keep all of the code in one file.  Simple.)
The code below eliminates the duplication.
NON-DUPLICATING CODE ALTERNATIVE:
#!/bin/bash
STRING=''    #Default to local (no ssh command)
[ "$HOSTNAME" != "Computer" ] && STRING='ssh Name@RemoteComputer'    #if not on "Computer", then add remote ssh login

eval $STRING \
"bash -c '
 <Block-of-commands>
'"

Unfortunately, the "eval" line fails.
"eval" has issues with adding anything after the STRING and with ending the line on a QUOTE.
I've tried several combinations of the "eval" line (BACK-SLASHES before QUOTES, putting "bash -c ' into the STRING, etc.), but they all fail.
I'd appreciate guidance or suggestions on how to just add or subtract "ssh Name@RemoteComputer" in the command which executes <Block-of-commands>.
Again, thanks for the help.

Surely the original command does not work properly on host Computer. Even if you take out the comment, whose embedded quotes mess up your quoting, the outer double quotes will prevent word splitting separating the bash, -c, and quoted block of commands.  Even if eval worked the way you hoped, then, the proposed alternative wouldn't work on host Computer either.

Don't use eval if you don't thoroughly understand it.  When you do thoroughly understand it, you will use it rarely, if ever, because you will know that it is dangerous, and that it is almost never the right tool for any job that should actually be done.

You can use ssh localhost ... and not worry about the distinction between local and remote hosts.

The command passed to ssh has to be double-quoted. Do not do it yourself. Instead, let bash do it. I propose first make a function of what you what to execute:
worktodo() {
    <Block-of-commands>
}

You can use shellcheck to check correctness of your commands. Then you can execute the function just locallyl. Or alternatively, you can serialize the function to a string with declare -f work and use printf "%q" to quote it properly for sourcing for the remote shell, and then execute it..
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "Computer" ]; then
   worktodo
else
   ssh "Name@RemoteComputer" "$(printf "%q " bash -c "$(declare -f worktodo); worktodo")"
fi

Do not store commands to execute as variables like STRING='ssh Name@RemoteComputer'. To store commands, use functions. You can make it a function.
if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "Computer" ]; then
   execfunc() { "$@"; }
else
   execfunc() {
      ssh "Name@RemoteComputer" "$(printf "%q " bash -c "$(declare -f "$1"); $1")"
   }
fi

execfunc work


Quoting in the shell is a source of great confusion, and I think the expression "The command passed to ssh has to be double-quoted" may contribute to that confusion.  Strings passed as arguments to ssh to be executed as a command on  the remote (or as arguments to that command) need to be properly quoted, but "proper" depends on context, and the sledge hammer of "always double quote" is not necessarily correct.  OTOH, an extensive explanation of quoting and the interaction with ssh is perhaps out of place.  But...reader beware.

You can just define a variable containing your commands and pass them to bash -c you don't need to use eval at all. Only small changes on your inital script are needed for that.
#!/bin/bash

# Define the block of commands as a variable
BLOCK_OF_COMMANDS="
echo \"Running commands\"
ls -l
"

if [ "$HOSTNAME" = "Computer" ]; then
    # Execute the block of commands locally by passing the BLOCK_OF_COMMANDS variable to bash -c
    bash -c "$BLOCK_OF_COMMANDS"
else
    # Do the same using SSH
    ssh Name@RemoteComputer "bash -c '$BLOCK_OF_COMMANDS'"
fi


Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 to understand why not to store commands in a variable but use a function instead and how to do that.

Thank you I just read it, for simple use cases this solution is absolutely ok. But I agree with more complex commands this will break.

You're welcome. The solution that'll also work for more complex cases isn't noticeably harder to write than this solution that won't so IMHO it's best to always just use the robust solution so you don't get a surprise in future when your script turns out to be one of the more complex cases.
